# Power Automate can't see Excel Macros

Tags: excel, vba, power-automate

I am trying to make a power automate task that runs a VBA Excel Macro. To isolate the issue, I've cut the power automate down to just "Manually trigger a flow"->"Run script". I can find the .xlsm file in the "Run script" action, but no scripts appear in the drop down. If I manually enter the name of a script (which exists in the file), and try to save the flow, I get an error message saying:

The dynamic operation request to API 'excelonlinebusiness' operation 'GetSingleScript' failed with status code 'BadRequest'. This may indicate invalid input parameters. Error response: { "status": 400, "message": "Unable to parse script reference. clientRequestId: dfb8f701-e033-4929-9fc4-3adabfbdecfe", "error": { "message": "Unable to parse script reference." }, "source": "excelonline-ne.azconn-ne-002.p.azurewebsites.net" }

What am I missing here?

[image: here is the error message]

I have tried adding in a "Get file metadata" action, based on the information in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o-H9BbywJQQ) but it hasn't helped and I think the video is out of date - I can see .xlsm files in "Run script", I just can't see any scripts.

I still get the same error.

Comment: You need to do some reading. Macros don’t work and are not an option to execute in the cloud. “Run script” is related to Office Scripts … https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/overview/excel

Comment: alternatively, you can use power automate desktop to run a VBA macro